# Java8: select min value from specific field of the objects in a list

Tags: java, java-8, minimum, java-stream

Suppose to have a class Obj

```
class Obj{

  int field;
}
```

and that you have a list of `Obj` instances, i.e. `List<Obj> lst`.

Now, how can I find in Java8 the minimum value of the int fields `field` from the objects in list `lst`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do

```
int min = list.stream().mapToInt(Obj::getField).min();
```

Answer (score 24):

```
   list.stream().min((o1,o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.field,o2.field))
```

Additional better solution from the comments by Brian Goetz

```
list.stream().min(Comparator.comparingInt(Obj::getField))
```

Comment: This would be better as:

    list.stream().min(Comparator.comparingInt(Obj::getField))

Comment: Didn't know that one, thanks, I think your solution is the best so far